# Silverlight UserControl

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have 2 user controls. My MainPage control and my edit functions control. My edit control uses WCF to update a database. Once this is done I need to reload the Mainpage control which searched the database to see the changes mad by the edit functions control.

I did this in an asp.net project by redirecting to the MainPage - do you know how this is done in Silverlight.

Comment: You can use 2 viewmodels and pass the main model as a parameter to the constructor of the edit model. Also you can use some kind of event aggregator, for examle Messenger class in the mvvm light library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so i did this by creating a Button at the top of my main page which fires a reload of the page. 
I then used the Visual tree helper to get the button and invoke it. I did this by:

1. Create a class to search Controls:
   public static class ControlFinder
   {
       public static T FindParent(UIElement control) where T : UIElement
       {
           UIElement p = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(control) as UIElement;
           if (p != null)
           {
               if (p is T)
                   return p as T;
               else
                   return ControlFinder.FindParent(p);
           }
           return null;
       }

   }
2. Find the Button within the controls:

   UserControl uc = ControlFinder.FindParent(this);
   UserControl mainControls = ControlFinder.FindParent(uc); 
   var PageGrid = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(mainControls, 0); 
   var StackPanel = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(PageGrid, 0);
   Button RefreshButton = (Button)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(StackPanel, 0);
3. Invoke the button event which fires the refresh
   ButtonAutomationPeer buttonAutoPeer = new ButtonAutomationPeer(RefreshButton);
   IInvokeProvider invokeProvider = buttonAutoPeer.GetPattern(PatternInterface.Invoke) as IInvokeProvider;
   invokeProvider.Invoke();